# Error al ejecutar Laravel en un hosting

Tags: php, laravel, json, laravel-5

Al cargar `Laravel` en un hosting compartido y el proyecto dentro de un subdirectorio comenzo a aparecer el siguiente error:

> PHP's json extension is required to use Monolog's NormalizerFormatter

Actualmente uso la versión `5.6` de `Laravel` y dentro del servidor modifique la versión de `PHP` a `7.2`.

Comment: fijate si en el panel del hosting hay una sección custom php.ini o habilitar extensiones, o habilitar extensiones PEAR/PECL. lo mas seguro es que ya esté instalado y falte habilitarlo con `extension=json.so` en el php.ini

Comment: ¿En que lugar del hosting puedo encontrar el archivo php.ini?

Comment: depende mucho del hosting, en algunos desde cpanel podes activar y desactivar extensiones. en otros con un `php.ini` en la raíz del proyecto funciona, en otros tenes que poner un archivo `phprc` o `php.ini` dentro de `/home/usuario/.php/versiondelphpporejemplo7.0/` en otros hay que setear una variable por medio de .htacess pra que te tome el `php.ini`

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos, contacte a la empresa de hosting con la cual trabajo como me indicaron varios y ellos habían modificado algo, por eso me mostraba el error.

Answer (score 1):

Si es un hosting compartido, no creo que tengas privilegios de instalación de paquetes así, por lo cual probablemente debas contactarlos para que instalen o te habiliten la extensión php-json.

Para futuros visitantes de esta pregunta, dependiendo de la distribución de linux pueden usar:

Centos

```
sudo yum install php72-php-json
```

Ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-json
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que habilitar la extensión para json como módulo de php. Esto puede no estar disponible al ser un hosting compartido y la solución puede variar según la empresa que usas y el panel del que disponga para gestionarlo.

Algunos se habilitan en un directorio de la raíz dónde hay archivos con las configuraciones (suelen ser pocos y lo detectarás rápidamente si encuentras un archivo php.ini) pero lo más común es encontrarte alguna sección en la parte donde editas las preferencias para el sitio virtual que gestionas.

Tal vez la mejor opción sería mirar en la documentación del propio panel de tu hosting o preguntar directamente al soporte de este.

Aún así, a modo orientativo te muestro un ejemplo con la captura de uno de mis hosting donde tengo por defecto todos los módulos instalados pero los activo mediante archivos de configuración:
[image: Ejemplo de directorios de configuración en mi hosting]